# Como ignorar a acentuação em uma pesquisa de banco de dados?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Preciso realizar uma busca de cidades.
No banco de dados está cadastrado por exemplo, `São Paulo`, `Viamão`, `Curitiba`, mas se o usuário tentar pesquisar a cidade de `São Paulo` por exemplo, digitando `Sao Paulo` (sem acentuação), nada é encontrado pois no banco está cadastrado com acentuação.

Tentei o seguinte:

```
select Municipio.descricao 
  from municipios as Municipio 
where  Municipio.descricao ilike '%Sao Paulo%'
```

Alguém sabe como fazer essa pesquisa ignorando a acentuação cadastrada no banco?

Comment: ...where  Municipio.descricao ilike '%Sao Paulo%' collate utf8_general_ci

Comment: acontece isso `ERROR:  collation "utf8_general_ci" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`

Comment: COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI Like '%Sao Paulo%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: Mesma coisa, da erro no `COLLATE`:  `ERROR:  collation "latin1_general_ci_ai" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`

Comment: Fiz uma função que resolveu, vou postar a resposta, mas agradeço a tentativa.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Esta collation é para o MySQL, esta questão é Postgresql

Comment: Ah sim, por isso não deu certo, obrigado @ClodoaldoNeto

Comment: desculpe, não reparei :) Clodoaldo Neto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No cake:

*Crio a função `remove_acento`*

```
$this->Cliente->query("create or replace function remove_acento(text)
        returns text as \$BODY$
            select translate($1, 'áàâãäéèêëíìïóòôõöúùûüÁÀÂÃÄÉÈÊËÍÌÏÓÒÔÕÖÚÙÛÜçÇ',
            'aaaaaeeeeiiiooooouuuuAAAAAEEEEIIIOOOOOUUUUcC');
            \$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;");
```

*Depois no `Paginator` chamo ela assim:*

```
$conditions[] = "remove_acento(Municipio.descricao) 
           ILIKE remove_acento('" . $filtro4 . "')";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `unaccent`:

```
where unaccent(Municipio.descricao) ilike unaccent('%Sao Paulo%')
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html

Para instalar como super usuário:

```
create extension unaccent;
```

Comment: Muito bom Clodoaldo, vou verificar com os responsáveis pelo servidor se é possível instalar essa ferramenta e farei uso da mesma.

Obrigado pela assiduidade !